# Android - Error Input String

Tags: java, android

Please, i am trying to insert data into my database but i ran into some errors with Android about input string.

Here is my code:

```
public void addEvent(){
            volunteerHandler volunteerHandler = new volunteerHandler(this);
            String activity_name = etActivityName.getText().toString();
            String location = etLocation.getText().toString();
            int date = Integer.parseInt(mydp.getDayOfMonth() + "/" + (mydp.getMonth()+1) + "/" + mydp.getYear());
            int time = Integer.parseInt(mytp.getHour() + ":" + mytp.getMinute());
            String volunteer_name = etVolunteerName.getText().toString();
            volunteerHandler.addVolunteer(activity_name, location, date, time, volunteer_name);
    }
```

Error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.igng.ivolunteer, PID: 6375
                                                                   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "31/3/2018"
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
                                                                       at com.igng.ivolunteer.Dashboard.addEvent(Dashboard.java:125)
                                                                       at com.igng.ivolunteer.Dashboard$1$1.onClick(Dashboard.java:101)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Well, in your opinion, what `int` value you expect to get by parsing string like "31/3/2018"?

Comment: Did you try debugging the error? `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "31/3/2018"` explains what's going wrong.

Comment: are you sure using `Int` for date ?

Comment: What datatype are my suppose to use to achieve the date format "31/3/2018"??...any idea please

Comment: L. Swifter, yes i used Int for date. I initially tried date datatype, but it didnt work for my database table

Answer (score 0):

Look at this error logcat:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "31/3/2018"

You can not parse your date into integer, you should save date with string type.

Comment: Hi, Sean, are my suppose to write the line of code like this:  String date = (mydp.getDayOfMonth() + "/" + (mydp.getMonth()+1) + "/" + mydp.getYear());

Comment: Yes, at least it can solve the problem about NumberFormatException, so that you can run normally.